# Can I use a single wire as the BT Antenna?

Tags: rf, bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy

I am using the following [BT Module](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/microchip-technology/RN4871U-V-RM118/RN4871U-V-RM118-ND/6130475?utm_adgroup=RF%20&utm_term=&slid=&gclid=CjwKCAiAluLvBRASEiwAAbX3GTWQSjnBznncsGB1r9fUWQgOdV0QRoZHm7YAXiz62Gcwhm3PGbz2jRoC5usQAvD_BwE&utm_campaign=Dynamic%20Search&%20RFID=&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google) and was wondering if I could just use a single wire as the antenna? I have seen wifi devices with a single wire soldered or connected to the board with a short run of the wire being used as the antenna.

Answer (score 1):

> could just use a single wire as the antenna?

Sure, that's called a monopole antenna. You'll have to make sure it's the right length and that you offer enough of a ground plane. Also, impedance matching is a thing, since the feedpoint impedance of a monopole usually isn't what you can use in a transmission line on a PCB.

> I have seen wifi devices with a single wire soldered or connected to the board with a short run of the wire being used as the antenna.

I doubt that. The things you've probably seen are small-diameter coax cables leading to a dipole, since that works better without a defined ground plane.

Sure, a random wire works better than no wire at all, but chip antennas are smaller and cheaper to assemble than wires, and would usually work at least as well.